# Transposing a table by self-join using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, matrix, pivot-table, self-join

I'm trying to find the right query to dynamically transpose the first row from table/matrix and have them side by side with other values,

Table1:

```
ID   | System1 | System2 | System3 | System4 |
1    |         | Admin   | Lunch   | Training|
2    | INFO    | INFO    | INFO    | INFO    |
3    | INFO    | INFO    | INFO    | INFO    |
4    | IN      | IN      | IN      | IN      |
```

The query should result in the following:

```
ID   | System1 | System1_1| System2 | System2_2 | System3 | System3_3 | System4 | System4_4 | 
2    | INFO    |          | INFO    | Admin     | INFO    | Lunch     | INFO    | Training  | 
3    | INFO    |          | INFO    | Admin     | INFO    | Lunch     | INFO    | Training  |
4    | IN      |          | IN      | Admin     | IN      | Lunch     | IN      | Training  |
```

As you can see I transposed the top row values into the related new column. This way the values belong to the same record, side by side.

How can I achieve this via a self join?

Comment: If this needs to be "dynamic" then a Self Join wouldn't be what you'd want; you'd want (dynamic) conditional aggregation. Though I don't see what needs to be dynamic in the above; are we missing more examples which could result in dynamic SQL being a requirement?

Comment: Sorry, I was over complicating it, the dynamic element isn't required at this stage. The answer below is sufficient for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self-join, you can do:

```
select t.id, 
    t.system1, t1.system1 as system1_1, 
    t.system2, t1.system2 as system2_1, 
    t.system3, t1.system3 as system3_1,
    t.system4, t1.system4 as system4_1
from mytable t
cross join mytable t1
where t.id > 1 and t1.id = 1
```